# Riley with a bonus clue

Tags: riddle

I’ll try another Riley...

> My prefix is a unit
>   My infix relates units
>   My suffix is found on shore
>   My whole always makes more
>   Bonus: My uffix is my whole

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Ampersand

My prefix is a unit

> Amp, short for ampere, unit of electric current

My infix relates units

> Per, e.g, *kilometres **per** hour*

My suffix is found on shore

> Sand

My whole always makes more

> The use of "&" implies there's more to come.

My uffix is my whole

> *And* is equivalent to &, 
> as @Fifth_H0r5eman points out "uffix" is the end of suffix so this works. 
>  also, as @Rubio points out, "uffix" is  suffix without the 's', the same as sand/and.

Comment: I think "Uffix" was intentional, since it is the end of suffix

Comment: @Fifth_H0r5eman I take your point, I've edited appropriately.

Comment: Everything is right. The reason “uffix” is intentional is just slightly more specific.

Comment: "uffix" is "suffix" without the first "S".

Comment: That was more my point, with Rubio being more direct about it :)

Comment: The "always" on the fourth line bothers me quite unreasonably much: in many (most?) programming languages, the whole happens to be the symbol for the bitmask (bitwise AND) operation, which is typically only used on unsigned integer values. In that use, it _never ever_ gives a result that is more than either of the operands.

Comment: @Fifth_H0r5eman You probably didn't notice the "s" connection though. It's a really well-made puzzle.

Comment: @wizzwizz4, I did, as the standard format is otherwise "suffix of my suffix" from other Rileys, I just wasn't as specific in pointing it out. I agree though, it's a nicely made puzzle, I often like the ones with answers like this, they feel very tidy to me.